# PHP, Docker, Selenium Grid: how to run tests?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

There are Docker containers: a local project (php-framework), Selenium Grid, Selenium Nodes (Chrome, Opera ...). How to run the tests generated using Selenium IDE (Python)?

Settings from docker-compose.yml like this:

```
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    volumes:
      - ./project/tests/Selenium:/tests
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    links:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - 5900
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to run your tests.
My favorite for WebApplications is to record a Test with Selenium IDE and export it as .side file.

You can **get Selenium IDE** here:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/

Now, make sure to **check the syntax for selenium-side-runner** and the **installation instructions**:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner

After that you can run the test against your hub with **selenium-side-runner** e.g.:

```
selenium-side-runner --server http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub --debug -c "browserName='chrome'" --output-directory ~/out ~/myrecordedtest.side
```

Side runner can be started on your local machine or on the host running your docker containers or inside a container.

If this works you could get started in coding some tests, which is a different way to generate tests.

I really like to use Zalenium which is a stack opensourced by Zalando.
There are some good tutorials which can be used with plain selenium hub too:
https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/